# add domain objects as classpath dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have gradle plugin which required certain objects to operate.
The problem is that those objects are domain object for another project, where that plugin is located.

For example I put plugin `jar` inside project folder. 
But the domains that plugin requires to use in runtime is located in `src/main/java/package/classX`.

How to make plugin use them?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem by adding these lines to my projects' buildscript into `dependencies` section

```
classpath files(['project_name/bin'])
```